# move left or right from point in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have written a script that does the function:

```
    eval(['VCathodicOh3(2,i) =' 'min(' 'data_' varnames{1} '(49000:51000,9));'])
```

In this, 'VCathodicOh3'  is made by taking data from column 9 in different variables that are organized in arrays (they are 1:100000 rows by 10 columns).

I want to, instead of just finding the min, also add something to this function so that it takes the min, finds the point at which that min is at, and then move 4 points to the left of that point.

Ex:

```
     min(data_var(49000:51000,9)) = -3.190
```

then lets say (50250, -3.190) is the point at which you find the min. I would like the script to move that point -4 (50246, y) and give me the new corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second output of `min` to tell you the index of the minimum value. You could then decrement this value by 4 to shift it to the left.

```
a = [5 3 2 1 0]
[~, ind] = min(a);

newval = a(ind-4)
```

If you have a 2D matrix, you can convert the linear index `ind` to rows / columns and decrement that:

```
a = magic(10);
[~, ind] = min(a);

[row,col] = ind2sub(size(a), ind);

newval = a(row, col-4)
```

As a side note, I would really discourage using dynamic variable names like you are and use a more appropriate data structure such as a cell array or `struct`. The usage of `eval` can get out of hand very quickly as I'm sure you've noticed.